# I have a "onclick" that runs 3 functions but only runs one?

Tags: javascript, function, button

So I have a button with onclick that runs 3 functions and each function is to display a random symbol.  So when I press the button, it should output 3 random symbols, but only one symbol it outputted when I click the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>MyFirstJavaScript</title>
</head>
<body>
<script>

function slots1()
{
    var slot1 = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
    if (slot1 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2663";
    }
    if (slot1 == 1) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2665";
    }
    if (slot1 == 2) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2666";
    }
    if (slot1 == 3) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2660";
    }

}



function slots2()
{
    var slot2 = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
    if (slot2 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2663";
    }
    if (slot2 == 1) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2665";
    }
    if (slot2 == 2) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2666";
    }
    if (slot2 == 3) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2660";
    }

}



function slots3()
{
    var slot3 = Math.floor(Math.random()*4);
    if (slot3 == 0) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2663";
    }
    if (slot3 == 1) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2665";
    }
    if (slot3 == 2) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2666";
    }
    if (slot3 == 3) {
        document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = "\u2660";
    }

}



</script>

<button type="button" value="Spin" name="SPIN"     onClick="slots1();slots2();slots3();">Spin</button>
<span id="value"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: logic problem. You set the innerHTML three times. Only the last one will be visible because each one overwrote the previous.

Answer (score 1):

Each function basically overrides the value that's changed by the previous one, so the only value you see is the result of `slots3()`. This following line is common to all your functions and it's your override:

```
document.getElementById('value').innerHTML = //some value;
```